# Weird sql backup from postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I created a backup of a table that I intended to change for experimental reasons. I created the backup with pgadmin by right-clicking on the respective table and select backup.

I expected the outcome to be a sql file that I can easily re-import. However, what I got is a non-sql file with weird content like this.

```
...

COPY "MyTable" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", "col15", gid) FROM stdin;
                0001-01-01 00:00:00 0           0                   010300000001000000050000006CE7FB29252C1641EC51B8F69B035641FF7C3FB5242C16417F9543139C0356416807EB9F282C16411B3048239C035641C871A714292C164185ECBC069C0356416CE7FB29252C1641EC51B8F69B035641  1
                0001-01-01 00:00:00 0           0                   010300000001000000050000009279C8741D2C1641E55949CD9B035641116745B41D2C16419E78CEB09B03564137DD2486192C16418FED7CA79B0356419EEFA746192C1641D9CEF7C39B0356419279C8741D2C1641E55949CD9B035641  2
                0001-01-01 00:00:00 0           0                   01030000000100000005000000C8EBA48EF92B1641B0E8D6349B0356413F25E724F92B1641BC5E9A549B035641C320B0F2FC2B1641643BDF5F9B035641C520B072FD2B164183C0CA419B035641C8EBA48EF92B1641B0E8D6349B035641  3
                0001-01-01 00:00:00 0           0                   01030000000100000005000000FC34EE9D092C164167D7BDCA9A03564120384BF9092C1641FC4465AB9A0356413EE3A51B062C16419CC420A09A03564144E048C0052C1641045779BF9A035641FC34EE9D092C164167D7BDCA9A035641  4

...
```

I can easily recognize that each line means a data record, each column is seperated by a tab and each empty content between two tabs means a "NULL" value, but how am I meant to reimport this without having to restructure the whole file manually?

And what does this "COPY" function mean, why did the backup file not simply create an "insert into" script?

Comment: That is valid SQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Ok. How do I import it then? Copy-Pasting it in the pgadmin sql editor gives me a syntax error exactly at the line where the non-standard sql begins.

Comment: On the same menu as "backup" from right-clicking, you have a "restore" menu item.

Answer (score 3):

That **is** a valid SQL file for Postgres (see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) for details). It can be run using the `psql` command line client. As I don't use pgAdmin, I can't tell if maybe that doesn't support `copy ... from stdin`.

If you want regular `insert` statements in the generated SQL script, you need to run `pg_dump` using the parameter `--inserts`. Again, [see the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) for details

Comment: is it possible to transform this dump into ordinary inserts? I have a lot of trouble with psql, which complains  about syntactic errors as well.

Comment: `psql` understands a dump from `pg_dump` without any changes. If you have problems running it, you should post a new question. There is no way to _convert_ an existing SQL script that uses the `COPY` command to one using `INSERT` statements. You will have to re-create the dump using `pg_dump`

Comment: PgAdmin does not understand `COPY`, nor any `psql` backslash-commands. Very frustrating when giving people instructions, only to find out they're using PgAdmin. This is why we should be making the core of `psql` a library that apps like PgAdmin can use to implement their own interactive SQL editors.